# Retornar valores filtrados no Shell Bash para inserção no BD

Tags: python, linux, shell

Estou elaborando um script em *python* que captura os **TOP 5** processos de consumo de memória ram e CPU da máquina, por enquanto o script está funcional apenas para **LINUX**, segue abaixo:

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Desenvolvimento Aberto
# shell.py

# Importar modulos do sistema operacional
import os
import subprocess 
import commands

# passando comando em uma variavel para pegar top 5 consumo de memoria
command_mem = '''ps aux --sort=-%mem | head -n 5 | jq -cR '[splits(" +")]' '''

# criando array do comando
value_mem = commands.getoutput(command_mem)

# exibir resultado
print("MEMORIA:\n"+value_mem)
```

**Output:**

```
["user+","10340","13.2","6.9","5119880","553860","?","Sl","ago12","4:46","/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java","-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions","-Xms64m","-Xmx1024m","-jar","/usr/share/dbeaver//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar","-os","linux","-ws","gtk","-arch","x86_64","-showsplash","-launcher","/usr/share/dbeaver/dbeaver","-name","Dbeaver","--launcher.library","/usr/share/dbeaver//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so","-startup","/usr/share/dbeaver//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar","--launcher.overrideVmargs","-exitdata","5ee801c","-vm","/usr/bin/java","-vmargs","-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions","-Xms64m","-Xmx1024m","-jar","/usr/share/dbeaver//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar"]
["user+","12548","1.1","4.1","1226988","332960","?","Sl","00:12","0:02","/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/wps","/home/user/Documents/script/shell-bash/pega-memoria-linux.txt"]
["user+","10062","3.2","3.6","1891904","286776","?","Sl","ago12","1:14","/usr/share/code/code","--type=renderer","--no-sandbox","--service-pipe-token=4B72CA3F1395A79FC84737040282E34F","--lang=pt-BR","--app-path=/usr/share/code/resources/app","--node-integration=true","--webview-tag=true","--no-sandbox","--background-color=#1e1e1e","--num-raster-threads=2","--enable-main-frame-before-activation","--enable-compositor-image-animations","--service-request-channel-token=4B72CA3F1395A79FC84737040282E34F","--renderer-client-id=9","--shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101"]
["user+","9494","0.1","2.1","1076224","169484","?","SLl","ago12","0:03","/opt/google/chrome/chrome"]
```

Eu gostaria que no campo **COMMAND** que é o último campo do comando `PS AUX` ele me retornasse apenas o nome do serviço/programa que está em execução, pois essa maneira que está vindo está dificultando subir os dados para o banco de dados pois o número de colunas se torna relativo por causa do campo **COMMAND**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque não usa a biblioteca `psutil` ? Ela é muito simples e pode ser usada em Windows, Linux, etc. Para o que você deseja, crie um objeto de `Process` e depois obtenha o nome do processo e o uso da CPU em porcentagem chamando os métodos `name()` e `cpu_percent()`. Exemplo:

```
import psutil

maiorConsumo = ("None",0.0)
interval = 1
cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()

for pid in psutil.pids():

    try:
        process = psutil.Process(pid)
        cpu_percent = process.cpu_percent(interval)/cpu_count
        name = process.name()
    except: continue

    if cpu_percent > maiorConsumo[1]:
        maiorConsumo = (name,cpu_percent)

print("Maior consumo: Name = {}  Uso = {}%".format(*maiorConsumo))
```

Com o `psutil` você pode obter muitas informações relacionadas ao seu sistema, incluindo redes e outros. Você pode extrair informações do processo como o diretório do programa, uso de CPU, nome do processo, ID do processo, conexões, uso de memória, além de conseguir gerenciá-lo.

Para instalar o `psutil` no windows digite `pip install psutil`. Clique [aqui](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) para ver sua documentação.

Comment: Não conhecia essa lib do py, muito obrigado por sua resposta, vou estudar mais ela, abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Modifiquei conforme minha necessidade, caso ajude alguém futuramente:

```
import psutil, datetime

process = []
veryConsumeCPU = ("None",0.0)
veryConsumeRAM = ("None",0.0)
cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()

for pid in psutil.pids():

try:
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    name = p.name()  # execute internal routine once collecting multiple info
    time = p.cpu_times()  # return cached value
    mem_percent = p.memory_percent(memtype="rss") # return cached value
    cpu_percent = p.cpu_percent(interval=1) / cpu_count # return cached value
    create_time = p.create_time()  # return cached value
    pid = p.ppid()  # return cached value
    status = p.status()  # return cached value
except: continue

process = [pid,name,cpu_percent,mem_percent,datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),time,status]
print("PID = {} Name = {}  Uso de CPU = {}% Uso de MEMORIA = {}% Criado em = {} Tempo corrente: = {} Status = {}".format(*process))

if cpu_percent > veryConsumeCPU[1]:
    veryConsumeCPU = (name,cpu_percent)
elif mem_percent > veryConsumeRAM[1]:
    veryConsumeRAM = (name,mem_percent)

print("Maior consumo CPU: Name = {}  Uso = {}%".format(*veryConsumeCPU))
print("Maior consumo RAM: Name = {}  Uso = {}%".format(*veryConsumeRAM))
```